# Database plugin to persist data offline in Icenium-based app

Tags: database, cordova, icenium

I am using Icenium to develop my mobile app. I wanted to know what is the recommended database solution to persist data offline on the device for Phonegap/Cordova based apps for iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

I am aware of [this SQLite plugin](https://github.com/Icenium/sample-sqlite) for Phonegap-based apps that works on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands right now you're going to have a hard time finding a SQLite plugin that is compatible across all three of those platforms. Without too much effort you could add this plugin and conditionally use it for WP8:

https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin

The only sure-fire solution for cross-platform dev at the moment is to use local storage as your offline data storage mechanism.